# Drag finger across divs like piano keys preventing mobile/tablet scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, touch

I am trying to create a widget/control for a website that functions kind of like a piano.
Think of 4-5 divs, one under the other, positioned absolute.

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <div class="quadrant" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; height: 20%></div>
   <div class="quadrant" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; height: 20%></div>
   <div class="quadrant" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; height: 20%></div>
   <div class="quadrant" style="position: absolute; top: 60%; height: 20%></div>
   <div class="quadrant" style="position: absolute; top: 80%; height: 20%></div>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to move his finger ACROSS THESE DIVS without lifting the finger! i.e. I do NOT want these to act as 'buttons' which require you to lift your finger between clicks, but more like points on a slider (the distinction being, you do not have to lift up your finger when moving a slider). I also want to trigger an event when the finger goes over a new div.

I've got it working nicely on desktop with a mix of css and mouse events but having a hell of a time on mobile and tablet. As soon as I try moving the finger as explained, the browser thinks the user is trying to scroll the whole page (Even when I shrink the page down to smaller than the tablets viewport).

How do I prevent this 'scroll ability'?

I've tried preventDefault() of touchstart and touchmove events; this shuts down the scrolling but it also means I can't track/selected the selected div.

Comment: Does it help: `.quadrant {touch-action: none;}` ???

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Thanks though